# Editable Combobox with ExtAspNet?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, extjs

Does anyone know how to achieve an editable combobox with [ExtAspNet](http://extaspnet.codeplex.com)?

The input element has its readonly attribute set, so I think I can just remove that attribute, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
    base.Render(new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter));
    writer.Write(strWriter.ToString().
        Replace("id: \"" + DropDownList1.ClientID + "\",",
                "id: \"" + DropDownList1.ClientID + "\",editable:true,hideTrigger:true,")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code for ExtAspNet, open the DropDownList.cs file in the WebControls folder. Locate the property called Editable, if its not there then paste this code.

public bool Editable
        {
            get
            {
                object obj = XState["Editable"];
                return obj == null ? false : (bool)obj;
            }
            set
            {
                XState["Editable"] = value;
            }
        }

this will create a property for the control. Now on the OnFirstPreRender method, add this line if its not there...

if (Editable)
            {
                OB.AddProperty("editable", true);
            }

Compile your solution and when you creating your user interface in the dropdownlist definition in your aspx file just add Editable="true" like this.

That should work.